# Get the page being created in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.5

I add the following event to the document:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e) {

});
```

and the event is triggered when a new page is to be viewed, my question is how to get the id of the page being created?
`$.mobile.activePage` is undefined and `getActivePage()` of page container widget throws error:

> cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'getActivePage'

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I used:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id
```

and it does not throw errors but it returns the id of the current page not the page to be created, any suggestions?

Comment: **how to get the id of the page**?? `id` belongs to any element in the page, not the page itself.

Comment: If you mean the `id` of `body`, then `body` tag doesn't need any `id`, because there is only one `body` tag exist in any valid `html` page.

Comment: jquery mobile has a dive with page role that is added to the DOM dynamically and the event corresponds to this event

Comment: How did the `id` of the page  is set??

Comment: Check jquery mobile documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `event.target`, here is a **demo**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
      function showme(e, ui){
        var activePage = $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("getActivePage").prop("id");
        $("#events").append("Event: "+e.type+" raised from: "+(activePage ? activePage : 'landing')+"<br>"); 
        if(activePage) {
          $("#events").append("Active Page: "+activePage+"<br>"); 
        } 
        if(e.target){
          if(e.target.id)
            $("#events").append("Target Page: "+e.target.id+"<br>") 
        } 
      } 
      $(document).on("pagecreate", function(e, ui) { showme(e, ui); }); 
    });
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Page 1</h1>
    <a href="#page-2" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Go to Page 2</a>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div id="events">
      </div>
      <hr>
      Click "Go to page 2"
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-2">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Page 2</h1>
    <a href="#page-1" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Back to Page 1</a>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      Page 2 has been created - Click back
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```